# Track App Version in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Google Analytics module( https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5081?2014113336 ) in my Titanium App.

1). Is there any way to track my app version to Google Analytics. In that module documentation no information regarding this.

2). How can I test Google Analytics in my app? After integrating GA, I didn't see any data on my GA account. (even realtime data also empty https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#realtime )

3). When creating new Account in Google Analytics, which one should I choose WebSite or App ( http://screencast.com/t/gE0nPfxKsD7 )?(What is the difference between both)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can send your app's version together with the tracking or on an event, for example:

```
    PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
        trackPage("/SomethingUseful/" + info.versionName);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "exception / namenotfound");
    }
```

2) If you have done everything corretly, it should start appearing after a few minutes

3) App

Comment: Today GA provides an official way, check this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#appVersion

Answer (score 4):

#### For Firebase Analytics

1. Log in to your Firebase Console -- https://console.firebase.google.com/ -- and click on your project.
2. Click on the `"Analytics Dashboard"`  icon in the Sidebar on the left-hand side. The icon looks like this:
3. Scroll down the page to the graph that has the title `"Users ▾ by App version"`.
4. In this graph box, click on `"View app versions ➔"` at the bottom-right.

It will show a detailed graph and table on one page, for the app versions in use.

**To filter the data for a specific app version, do this:**

5. Scroll to the top-left of the page. Click on `"Add Filter +"`
6. In the "Build filter" section on the right, click on `"Select dimension"` -> **App version**
7. Click on one or more available app version names in the `"Select dimension values"` button, to show only the results from the chosen versions.
8. Press `"Apply"`

**To see the breakdown of Android OS versions used or iOS versions used, do this:**

9. Scroll down to the table. The left-most column should have the title `"App version ▾"`. Click this title.
10. In the popup menu, select `"OS with version"`.

The table and graph will update to show the OS versions in use for your app.

---

#### For the previous Google Analytics

The support staff say there is a way to use a **Segment** to filter the data for a specific app version, without needing extra code in the app:

1. View any Report in your Analytics account, such as Audience -> Overview.
2. Click **"Add Segment"**
3. Click **"NEW SEGMENT"** to open the segment builder
4. Click on **Advanced -> Conditions**
5. Click on the filter "Ad Content" to change it. **Search for "App Version"** and use that, and define your app version name.
6. Name and Save the filter after selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

1-> yes , you can send the app version by fetching it through Package Manager and sending it as a String. There is no specific way defined by GA.

2-> Usually the GA data is visible after sometime on Google Analytics Dashboard. Check after a day probably.

3-> If you want to track an app usage, choose app and if you are tracking website choose WebSite

Answer (score 0):

for point 1. you can set the app version in tracker:
mTracker.setAppVersion("xx.xx.xx");
then you can see the app version in the admin panel.