# Track percentage of users on each App Version

Tags: ios, google-analytics, version

I am currently developing an app for iOS and want to know how I could track how many users are using each version of the app in the future.

Is there a way I could get Google analytics to track this or can I tell how many people updated through iTunes Connect?

I want to find out how many people are using each version of the app.

(e.g. 10% version 1, 82% version 2 and 8% version 3....)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813934/track-app-version-in-google-analytics) about app version tracking but it is only on android. Any different for iOS?

If any code is needed to be added, I would need it to be Objective-C, since I have written the app in Objective C, not Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to solve this problem such as using Itunes connect, Google Analytic (similar alternatives flurry, Piwik etc...) as stated...

Itunes connect provides very basic information such as number of downloads and updates but does't go into proper details about version and build number.

Google Analytic is by far the best option as it allow to have a custom property when you push information about your app like version number etc... by default it intended for getting insight of page views and touches etc but you allowed to create your own. Flurry Piwik are quite similar to Google not really used these tools too much i but they mostly do they same.

**Example with GAI with [Custom Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets):**

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
// Set the custom dimension value on the tracker using its index.
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]
       value:@"Premium user"]
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:@"Home screen"];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:@"premium"
                                                  forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
```

Third approach would be to send app build information in NSBundle when ever your make a external request for example with Rest Api server... I send this version number with the HTTP header i.e X-App_Version.